# Child div not taking the height of parent div in bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap tab in which the children div should take the height is the parent div. As the content of the children div will dynamically change, i cannot set the height of the children div. Right now i am calculating the height using jQuery and its working fine for tab1 but in tab2, the same jQuery code is not working. This is the online link where you will be able to see the the blue colored div is not taking the parent div height. http://www.anotheritdude.com/clients/index.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ////for func block////
  $('.func_left').each(function() {
    var parentheight = ($(this).parent().height());
    $(this).height(parentheight);

  });
  ////for user block////
  $('.user_left').each(function() {
    var parentheightUser = ($(this).parent().height());
    $(this).height(parentheightUser);
  });
});
```

```css
.func_block {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px #ff732f solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.func_left {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ff732f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.func_right {
  float: right;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #fff;
  color: #ff732f;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 85%
}

.user_block {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px #5eaeff solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.user_left {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #5eaeff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.user_right {
  float: right;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #fff;
  color: #5eaeff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 85%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
    <div class="func_block">
      <div class="func_left" style="background: #ff732f;"> HR </div>
      <!--recurring blocks-->
      <div class="func_right"> test content </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->

    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <div class="func_block">
      <div class="func_left" style="background: #ff732f;"> PSR </div>
      <div class="func_right"> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span>        <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test conten,t test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span>        <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <div class="user_block">
      <div class="user_left"> HR </div>
      <div class="user_right"> <span class="user_content">test content</span> </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <div class="user_block">
      <div class="user_left"> HR </div>
      <div class="user_right"> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span>        <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test conten,t test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span>        <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do? I've used `display: flex` instead of `table`, removed `float` properties and the jQuery.

```css
.func_block {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px #ff732f solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.func_left {
  background: #ff732f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.func_right {
  background: #fff;
  color: #ff732f;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 85%
}

.user_block {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px #5eaeff solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.user_left {
  background: #5eaeff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.user_right {
  background: #fff;
  color: #5eaeff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 85%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
    <div class="func_block">
      <div class="func_left" style="background: #ff732f;"> HR </div>
      <!--recurring blocks-->
      <div class="func_right"> test content </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->

    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <div class="func_block">
      <div class="func_left" style="background: #ff732f;"> PSR </div>
      <div class="func_right"> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span>        <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test conten,t test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span>        <span class="func_content">test content</span> <span class="func_content">test content</span> </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <div class="user_block">
      <div class="user_left"> HR </div>
      <div class="user_right"> <span class="user_content">test content</span> </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <!--recurring blocks-->
    <div class="user_block">
      <div class="user_left"> HR </div>
      <div class="user_right"> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span>        <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test conten,t test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span>        <span class="user_content">test content</span> <span class="user_content">test content</span> </div>
    </div>
    <!--recurring blocks-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS only using a flexbox. The default setting for `align-items` is 'stretch', meaning they will cover from top to bottom.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 40%;
  border: thin solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Update</div>
  <div class="right">Insert</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ovokuro thanks a lot. You are right, i didnt have to use jquery. Used flex and its working fine now